# $$PLSQL in oracle to postgresql alternative

Tags: oracle, postgresql, oracle11g, plpgsql

while doing the testing in migrating oracle to PostgreSQL i am facing issue in code:-

```
create or replace PROCEDURE clear_delete_tables
/*
  clear_delete_tables

  Truncate all the del_ tables

*/
IS

  v_code NUMBER;
  v_errm VARCHAR2(64);

  CURSOR cur_del_tables IS
  SELECT table_name
  FROM user_tables
  WHERE table_name LIKE 'DEL!_%' ESCAPE '!';

BEGIN
  For i in cur_del_tables
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' || i.table_name;
  END LOOP;

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      v_code := SQLCODE;
      v_errm := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1 , 64);
      log_entry($$PLSQL_UNIT, v_code || ' - ' || v_errm);  
END clear_delete_tables;
```

What is the replacement in $$PLSQL_UNIT in PostgreSQL? How I can change the entire code to compatible in PostgreSQL?

Comment: As precised in the oracle documentation : $$PLSqL_UNIT is a VARCHAR2 literal that contains the name of the current PL/SQL unit (https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS002). You will not have an Oracle unit in your PostgreSQL instance. Seems to me that is a log system. Maybe you need to rethink your log system philosophy to be more complient to the PostgreSQL one.
And for the rest : you need to learn both plsql and plpgsql to fulfill the objective of migrate an oracle code to a postgres one. Like said on many posts : we are here to help, not to do your job for you.

Comment: (without any hard feelings ;) )

Comment: Hi Jaisus, thanks for your kind reply. i have also read the all the blogs related to this article already , however i have not found the any suitable solution related to this that's why i have raised the question here. anyway i will rethink on log system philosophy.

Comment: Hi ,I found the answer use the pg_context as solution.    create or replace PROCEDURE clear_protect_tables
/*
clear_protect_tables

Truncate all the prot_ tables

*/
IS
v_code NUMBER;
v_errm VARCHAR2(64);

CURSOR cur_prot_tables IS
SELECT table_name
FROM user_tables
WHERE table_name LIKE 'PROT!_%' ESCAPE '!';

BEGIN
FOR i IN cur_prot_tables
LOOP
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' || i.table_name;
END LOOP;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
v_code := SQLCODE;
v_errm := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1 , 64);
log_entry(PG_CONTEXT, v_code || ' - ' || v_errm);
END clear_protect_tables;